# How to calculate the ratio insert/select against a table to manage the index in Sybase ASE?

Tags: sybase

To create/manage indexes of a table, it is important to know the ratio insert/select or modification/reporting. For instance, if there are more INSERTS than SELECT against a table, we should try to create only a few small indexes not to impact the INSERT performance.

How to calculate this ratio in Sybase ASE 15.5 and later?

Does it make sense to run the following?

```
select "Table"=object_name(ObjectID), IndexID, PagesRead, PagesWritten, Operations
from master..monOpenObjectActivity
where DBID=db_id("DBNAME") and ObjectID=object_id('TableNAME')
order by IndexID
```

Comment: Actually I did not get the chance to proceed further but I realized that this SQL only catches information for the last few minutes (depending on the MDA pipe size). So to get relevant information, I think we should calculate delta values for monOpenObjectActivity since the previous call in a session. See perfect SP described in [http://www.sypron.nl/mda.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20190204162606/http://www.sypron.nl/mda.html)